# Sharing an adapter between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have two fragments nested within another fragment.  One is a list view, and one is a ViewPager, with the viewpager's content being details of a selected list view item.  Obviously, they both use the same adapter.  The contents of the adapter is refreshed every, say, 5 seconds, so I need to keep the adapter used by both fragments in sync.

What would be the best way to go about keeping the adapter in sync between the two fragments?

I was thinking of storing the adapter in a retained non-ui fragment, making all the update calls within this fragment.  This would however require I constantly make pass the updated adapter to the child fragments and call `notifyDataSetHasChanged` in each fragment

Comment: 1 use ContentProvider, 2 its query() method retirns a Cursor which is used by a [Simple]CursorAdapter, 3 just pass an Uri between Fragments

Comment: I am trying to share an adapter between two fragments.  a Complex java object.  A Content Provider would be nice to share objects that are parcelable or are composed of simple primitives.  However this is not the scenario i am in

Comment: what Complex object cannot be represented by a Cursor ?

Comment: It seems I was looking at the default content provider used to manage databases. Anyways, the android developer guides http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html mention that content providers should really only be implemented for use with applications outside of your own.

Comment: so if you want not to use a custom CP then create a singleton Adapter and use it wherever you want